# Select where in multiple pairs - postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, exists, postgresql-9.4, where-in

I want to find all rows that match a list of pairs (multiple columns) and my query is not working. I get results if I only have a list of either column, but not when they are paired.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE (name,age) IN (('john',23),('jane',50),('john',44))
```

I saw posts about using EXISTS but I don't know how to convert this query.

I checked my database and it should return 8 rows but it is returning an empty table

Comment: Show the complete test case, with executable SQL, in text form.  The above SQL is correct as is, assuming your types make sense.  Here's a test case: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4f8fb12c20e907699c3b04600c2b3087

Comment: The query is correct. What exactly is the problem you have?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.4 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I checked my database and it should return 8 rows but it is returning an empty table

Your check is wrong.  The query is doing what you intend.

One possibility is that the names are incorrect because they have additional characters -- perhaps hidden.  You can easily check this.  Does this return anything?

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE name = 'john';
```

If this returns no rows and you think it should, then you need to figure out what is going wrong.  Does this condition work?

```
WHERE name LIKE '%john%'
```

The issue could be spaces at the beginning of the name, hidden characters, or look-alike characters.

If the first query does return rows, then the problem could be with `age`.  Does this return anything?

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE name = 'john' AND age = 23;
```

A problem with `age` is more subtle, but one possibility is a floating point representation, where the value is really 22.9999999997 rather than 23.

Comment: Thanks, it was a complete oversight on my side. I has the search_path to an older version. My code works. Also your comments helped with edge cases.

Answer (score 4):

You should use as explained below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t
WHERE (col1, col2) 
       IN ( VALUES (val1a, val2a), (val1b, val2b)) ;
```

Your Query would be:-

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE (name, age) IN ( VALUES ('john',23),('jane',50),('john',44));
```

Comment: The `VALUES`  clause is not needed `(name,age) IN (('john',23),('jane',50),('john',44))` is perfectly valid SQL

Comment: Agree, Both the expressions are valid. (name,age) IN ( VALUES ('john',23),('jane',50),('john',44)); & (name,age) IN ( ('john',23),('jane',50),('john',44));